# how to load nested relationship in laravel resource

Tags: php, laravel

I know I can load nested relationship in Laravel by a simple dot but I need to know if it's possible to load nested in resource and use it in API something like below:

```
  public function toArray($request)
    {
return [
     'Room' => AccommodationRoomResource::collection($this->firstrelation.NetstedRelation),
 ];
```

and my second question is that can I just load some certain fields of it as I don't need all the data to be loaded and make it so messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is Eager Loading. There is [a documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) for that. Refer to **Eager Loading By Default** section.

In a nutshell, you should add `$with` property to your model:

```
...
protected $with = ['room']; /// given that relation name is 'room'
...
```